# 建設的なコメントとはどういうものですか？

Tags: 討議, コメント

[コメント１](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/11772/autotools-%E5%90%91%E3%81%91%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E8%A6%8F%E7%B4%84%E3%81%AF%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B#comment10853_11772)：質問自体は漠然としているが、回答してくれそうなコメントに期待したが回答は行われていない
[コメント２](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2190/prolog%E3%81%A7%E7%B9%B0%E3%82%8A%E8%BF%94%E3%81%97%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%82%92%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%86%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95#comment742_2190)：編集の強要？
[コメント３](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12268/xampp%E3%81%A7403%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AB%E9%96%A2%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6#comment11165_12268)：そこまで詳細な情報が必要なのか疑問に思うコメント、ディレクトリ構造が変われば新しい質問として成立する？

[scala scalikejdbcでのupdateについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6484/scala-scalikejdbc%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AEupdate%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)
見ていて気持ちのいいコメントのやりとり

[removeFromSuperview時にanimateWithDurationのcompletionにEXC_BAD_ACCESS](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6369/removefromsuperview%E6%99%82%E3%81%ABanimatewithduration%E3%81%AEcompletion%E3%81%ABexc-bad-access)
解決に至らないながらもかなりの奮闘が伺えるコメント

いろいろなコメントがありますがどのようなものが建設的ですか
自分は、４番目と５番目が回答を建設的だと思うのですが

【追記】
どういったコメントが有益ですか

また、建設的という言葉をうまく理解できないのですが

謝辞
コメントで指摘くださった方ありがとうございます。
タグ付けや修正ができないというメタの仕様は全く知りませんでした。

Answer (score 5):

[建設的とは - Weblio辞書](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BB%BA%E8%A8%AD%E7%9A%84)

> その事の良さを積極的に認めた上で，さらに良くしていこうとするさま。物事の成立や進行をおし進めようとするさま。

---

SOの目標は「[どの質問に対してもベストアンサーを用意すること](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)」であり、コメントは「情報の追加を依頼したり、質問または回答を明確に」するためのものだと明記されています。

つまり質問に対するコメントは「良い質問」にするためのものです。上記ツアーページには次のように書かれており、良い質問の例も挙げられています。

> **質問は、実用的に詳細に**
>   自分が経験した実際の問題に関する質問に主眼を置いてください。どのようなことを試してみたか、そして具体的に何をしようとしているかを記述してください。

したがって、良い質問（あるいは回答）にするという目的に沿った内容であれば、そのコメントは建設的と言って差し支えないでしょう。質問あるいは回答において不明確な点を尋ねることや、誤りの指摘などは十分に建設的です。書式を整える依頼も建設的です。どのような環境で発生した事象なのかを尋ねることも建設的です。これらはコメントを付けた人自身が回答を投稿するかどうかは無関係です。

一方で、単なるお礼だとか、コメント投稿者同士での場外乱闘的な議論などは建設的とは言いがたいです。質問あるいは回答そのものの質を高めることに寄与しないからです。

他のサイトへの単なるポインタだけをコメントとして投稿するのが建設的かどうかは議論の分かれるところだと思います。

なお、回答をするにあたってコメントで詳細を尋ねるのはむしろ当然のことだと考えます。一昔前に「[顧客が本当に必要だったもの](http://blog.livedoor.jp/dankogai/archives/50852058.html)」というフレーズが流行りましたが、質問者が暗黙の了解あるいは当然の前提と考えて言及しないことによって認識の齟齬が容易に発生します。まして文字情報だけでは質問者の意図を汲み取るにも限界があります。言わなくてもそこは判れよ、というのは文脈やバックボーンを共有できている仲でしか通用しません。得てして当たり前だと思っている点に見落としがあったりするものです。要件定義でひたすらクライアントにヒアリングをすることに似ています。

回答者も限りある時間を割いて回答しています。質問をするより回答をするほうが、より大きな労力が必要となることが大半です。質問者からの少ない情報を基にして意図を汲んだつもりで回答をしたものの、実は的外れの回答だった、などという事態が発生すれば、それは質問者にとっても回答者にとっても、そして後から検索などでたどり着くであろう閲覧者にとっても、誰にも得になることがありません。建設的なコメントはこのような悲劇を回避するのに役立ちます。

Answer (score 3):

建設的の言葉の[意味は検索](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E5%BB%BA%E8%A8%AD%E7%9A%84&oq=%E5%BB%BA%E8%A8%AD%E7%9A%84&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i61.33886j0j4&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)するといろいろなページで確認することができます。
<sup>簡潔に説明するのなら積極的な行動と言ったところでしょうか。</sup>

その中でも特に他の言葉と対比させ意味を明らかにしている[ページ](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q127004422)があります。
そのページでは非建設的,悲観的,楽観的,破壊的,建設的の5つでこのページに当てはめ解説をしています。その解説に習いながら以下の例でコメントではどうなるかを考えてみます。

> １．コンパイルの警告の質問 
>   ２．誰も知らない言語の構文に関する質問 
>   ３．アルゴリズムの質問

- 非建設的

１.警告とかどうでもいい
2.そんなのしらねー
3.教科書をよく見なおしてください。

- 悲観的

1.警告なんて誰も知りたいと思ってなんていないです。
2.そんなマイナーな言語やめたほうがいいですよ。
3.アルゴリズムなんて簡単に説明できるわけ無いじゃん。

- 楽観的

1.警告でもコンパイルできるじゃん。そんなの無視しときなよ。
2.誰か知っている人が答えてくれると思いますよ
3.使い方さえわかればそれで十分でしょ。

- 破壊的

1.コンパイラを変更すれば同じ警告は出ませんよ
2.あなたには向いてません。別の言語に入門してください。
3.リバースエンジニアリングは犯罪です。

- 建設的

1.警告文も良いコードを書くためには必要な知識です。警告文とコードを示してもらえますか。
2.初めて聞く言語ですが、なにか参考にした教科書、ページ等はありますか。過去に同じ経験をした人がいるかもしれません。
3.アルゴリズムそのものの簡潔な説明ですか？それともアルゴリズム中の計算量を減らすテクニックの質問ですか？

---

ここから質問文の具体例を分類してみたいと思います。

[コメント１](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/11772/autotools-%E5%90%91%E3%81%91%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E8%A6%8F%E7%B4%84%E3%81%AF%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B#comment10853_11772)これは建設的です。良さを認める部分は投票でも十分に行えますし、書かなくても心の中にとどめているのかもしれませんし、書くとコメントが長くなってしまいます。

[コメント２](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2190/prolog%E3%81%A7%E7%B9%B0%E3%82%8A%E8%BF%94%E3%81%97%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%82%92%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%86%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95#comment742_2190)言い換えの積極的な行動を考慮するとコメントとしては非建設的かもしれません。編集も積極的な行動の一つとして考えることや、質問者の表現を尊重している可能性があるためです。

[コメント3](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12268/xampp%E3%81%A7403%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AB%E9%96%A2%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6#comment11165_12268)門外漢なので適切に判断できるかわかりませんが、質問者が一般的な回答を求めている場合は非建設か破壊かもしれませんが、エラーの解決という具体的な指針が示されていますので建設的です。