# 「コードをブラッシュアップする方法を教えてください」系の質問をするときに気をつけるべき点を教えてください

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方, 話題の範囲

プログラムを改善する方法を尋ねる以下のような質問はオントピックであったりそうでなかったりします。
オフトピックとしてクローズされないためにはどういう条件を満たす必要がありますか？

> 想定通りに動作するコードを書くことができましたが気に入らない箇所があります。
> その部分をより良い書き方にしたいのですがどういう風に書き換えれば良いですか？
>
> ```
> (想定通りに動作するコード)
> ```

Comment: 問題がなければこの質問をコミュニティwikiに変換していただければと思います。

Comment: コミュニティ wiki は編集をより気軽にできるようにする仕組みですが、特にメタの質問に対しては適用する必要性が薄いように感じるのでいったん様子見とさせてください。

Comment: 過去の関連討議: [コードレビュー的な質問はどこまでOKですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2939) , [「より良いコードを提示してください」などのコードレビュー系の質問は認められますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3477)

Comment: オフトピックになりそうな類似の質問に対して「質問文のこういう点が問題視されています」「こういう風に質問文を改善することが考えられます」というfaq的なものになったらいいなと思ったので、コミュニティwikiとするには不適切であってもこの質問も目的にあうように積極的に編集してもらえたらと思います。

Comment: コメント欄で本題自体とは関係の薄い会話が続いていたため、その部分をチャットに移動しました。本来であればこの部分は別途メタで質問いただくと取扱いやすいかなと思います： https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140887/discussion-on-question-by--

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[「コードレビュー的な質問はどこまでOKですか？」の回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2953)でオフトピックの例を書きましたが、書き方のテクニックなどを具体化して回答してみます。

下記の条件を満たしている質問は、いわゆるコードレビュー的な質問(以下、レビュー質問)であってもマイナス投票やクローズがされにくいと感じています。

- 質問の目的とゴールが明確である
- 質問内容に関係のない思惑が(透けて見え)ない
- 我を張らない

逆に言うとレビュー質問に限らず、上記のいずれかから逸脱する質問はマイナス投票やクローズさせる傾向にあります。

---

以下は各項目の説明です。
主観的な長文ですがご容赦ください。

#### 質問の目的とゴールが明確である

通常の質問でも指摘されることがありますが、特にレビュー質問では不明確な例が多い印象を受けます。

不明確な例：「コードをきれいにしてほしい」「速いコードにしたい」「より良いソートアルゴリズムはないか」
明確な例：「ネストが深く可読性が低いので、○○のネストを減らす方法はないか」「○○の実行部分が○件で○分かかり実用上問題があるので○秒以内に収められるロジックにしたい」「クイックソートを改造したサンプルコードを実行すると、下記のデータでは計算量が`O(n log n)`を越えるのはなぜか」

目的とゴールが不明確なレビュー質問の何が問題なのかというと、回答者が何を解決したいのかを推測(要件定義)し、課題に対するゴールを設定(基本設計)し、回答例を記述(コーディング)する全工程をこなさなければならないところです。
これはいわゆる**丸投げ質問よりも労力をかけている**気分になります。
もしあなたが職場で忙しい時に同僚から「ここでエラーが出るから相談させて」ではなく「このコードをリファクタリングして」という声を掛けられた時に「もうそれは質問ではなく**作業依頼**なのでは？」と感じるのではないでしょうか。

#### 質問内容に関係のない思惑が(透けて見え)ない

レビュー質問から少し脱線しますが、「学校の課題が分かりません」という質問はあまり高評価を受けないようです。
私はこの質問の是非について答えを持ちませんが、技術的な関心のない人が単位欲しさに課題の丸投げ質問をする姿が裏側に見え隠れする時に、何らかの心情的な不満が生じて積極的な回答をためらう回答者もいます。

ひるがえって本題です。
もしも「レビュー質問する俺のスキルは高いから、質問のコードを高い次元で理解する奴だけ回答しろ。回答は俺が評価してやる。さあSOjaの諸君は俺を満足させられるかな？」という思惑が透けて見える質問があるとするならば、それはQ&Aというより**質問者主催のコードゴルフ**に分類される可能性があり、その質問への回答を心情的に敬遠する回答者もいます。

SOjaにコードゴルフを明示的に禁止する規約はないはずですが、[買い物リスト質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1381)と同様に**正解がない質問**には悪い印象を抱かれる可能性があります。
また、回答が質問者に添削や採点されたとなると、少なくとも私はしょんぼりします。
私は技術的に困っている人の役に立ちたくて回答をしているのであって、ダメ出しをされたくて回答をしているのではありません。

「楽に単位がほしい」「回答者を使って自己の技術力を試したい」というような**技術的な疑問とは別の要求や意図**はひた隠していただいた方が、回答する側も回答に集中できるというのがここでの主張です。

#### 我を張らない

仮に「レビュー質問が悪いとどこにも書いてない」「SOjaの使い方は私のやり方が正しい」など、水掛け論、詭弁、法令の連呼を用いて**自己が正義**であると標榜し続ける方が質問したとします。
他者の指摘コメントを受け付けずに延々とコメントが続く質問に対して[建設的](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)な回答は付きにくいですし、コメントで双方が疲弊しているのを見るだけで私は悲しい気分になります。
cf: [建設的なコメントとはどういうものですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1992)

その一方で「初心者です。何も分かりません。コードの良くないところを丁寧に教えてください」など**自己を謙遜**して紹介するレビュー質問もあまり良い印象を持たれないようです。
特に「初心者です」という宣言は**親切な対応を強要する**意図があると受け取られかねません。質問者本人が無自覚であったとしてもです。
例えば私はJavaを業務プロジェクトで使用しないアマチュアですので、「私はJava超初心者です(趣味で20年利用)！」と言い張れるかもしれませんが、Javaの理解度の指標にはなりません。

またSOjaのシステムは、ヘルプで提示された使い方のレールに沿って利用することを前提に設計されています。
**独自のルールや文体**を良しとされるのは結構ですが、あまりにもシステムの設計から逸脱しすぎるのではなく、質問文では敬語で淡々と質問に関連する事実を羅列するのが回答者の理解を得やすいと感じています。

上記のことから、Q&Aサイトで"I Me Mine"を前面に押し出すのは適切な回答を得る観点から望ましからぬ場合があります。

---

レビュー質問に限らない意見を長々と語りましたが、質問する時は明確な回答しやすい質問を心がけ、丸投げにならず、高圧的でも卑屈でもなく対等な態度でルール/マナーに従うことで、職場またはSOjaの忙しい同僚が気持ちよく協力しやすい質問になるのではないでしょうか。

それと問題解決した後には、15円くらいの飴やチョコ[など](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1736)で返礼するとさらに喜ばれるかもしれません。

Comment: 「職場またはSOjaの忙しい同僚が気持ちよく協力しやすい質問」、全てがこれ基準にしていませんか？回答者の言う事に理由をつけてNGを出すことが、その質問のマイナス理由になっていては技術情報サイトとしてどうかと思いますよ。

Answer (score 3):

ブラッシュアップに限らず、回答の技術的な内容ではなく、質問者の主観によって回答の承認が決定される質問はオフトピックと思われます。より具体的には

- 質問文に挙げられた条件を満たした回答がなされ
- 回答に対して何等かの不足を指摘する必要がなく
- でもその回答を承認しない

という状況が成立する、もしくは成立すると思われる場合、これは主観的な質問であると判断できるのではないでしょうか。

[std::mapの初期化を綺麗にしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/91776/4236) はこれが該当すると考えます。逆に [プログラムの簡略化](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/92161/4236) は今のところ普通に受け入れられています。

このことからブラッシュアップは普通にオントピックであり、質問者の主観によって回答の承認が決定される質問がオフトピックというだけではないでしょうか？

Comment: 不足は必ず暗に指摘してますし、修正は依頼するとコメントが削除されたりしましたよ。